# how to create a new column after groupby count?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to create a new column with group by and count.
However it throws error "incompatible index of inserted column with frame index"

```
import pandas as pd

#read csv
df1 = pd.read_csv('hi.txt',sep = '\t')#provide name and sheet of excel file
a=df1.groupby(['c','t']).count()
df1['difference']=a
print(df1)
```

Input :

```
coun    id  cat
A   12  90
U   13  91
```

Comment: could you show the output of `df1.index` and `df1.columns`?

Comment: output of df1.index = RangeIndex(start=0, stop=4, step=1)

Comment: output of d1.columns = Index(['country', 'poi id', 'category'], dtype='object')

Comment: try: `df1.groupby(['country','category']).transform('count')`

Comment: Can You select the count directly `df1.groupby(['country','category']).count()[['country' 'poi id']]` ?
Also maybe something like [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) can help You ?
`df1.groupby(['country','category']).count().unstack('category)`

Comment: I think you are looking for transform. I have added a answer. Please check it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
new_df=df.groupby(['category','country'],sort=False).country.count().to_frame('count').reset_index()
print(new_df)
```

---

```
   category country  count
0      9910     AUS      2
1      7310     NZL      1
2      9910     NZL      1
```

Comment: df1.groupby(['country','category']).transform('count') is working fine , but it gives rise to duplicate  ```
 country  poi id  category  diference
0     AUS      12      9910          2
1     AUS      13      9910          2
2     NZL      14      7310          1
3     NZL      15      9910          1
```

Comment: if this is because transform extends the result of each group to each row of each group. If you don't want this you can use `reset_index`. See my updated answer :) In any case your problem is that I was assigning a data frame to a column that is a series by definition (difference)

Comment: please, tell me if my updated answer solve your question and consider accept my answer:)

Comment: why do you do that assignment? you cannot assign a data frame: 'a' to a column of another data frame df ['count']? What is your expected output?

Comment: expected output```
country category count
AUS 9910 2
NZL 7310 1
NZL 9910 1
```

Comment: why country AUS is 2 in count column?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201894/discussion-between-tushar-dhoke-and-ansev).